# Why is socket.io stuck in an infinite loop after emitting encrypted message

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Before I added the encryptClient() function to the emit, it was working perfectly but now when it's run it gets stuck with the following error

Error:

```
Uncaught InternalError: too much recursion
isBinary is-binary.js:20
hasBinary is-binary.js:36
hasBinary is-binary.js:45
hasBinary is-binary.js:45
hasBinary is-binary.js:45
hasBinary is-binary.js:45
hasBinary is-binary.js:45
hasBinary is-binary.js:45
hasBinary is-binary.js:45
hasBinary is-binary.js:45
hasBinary is-binary.js:45
```

This is all of the relevant code, I believe mostly just the index.html is relevant but I included everything that could be a problem just in case:

index.html:

```
<script >

    var socket = io();

    var messages = document.getElementById('messages');
    var form = document.getElementById('form');
    var input = document.getElementById('input');

    form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
       // var cipherText = encryptClient();
        
        if (input.value) {
            socket.emit('chat message', encryptClient());  
            input.value = '';
            console.log("encrypted message sent")
        }
    });

    socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
        var item = document.createElement('li');
        item.textContent = msg;
        messages.appendChild(item);
        window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    });
</script>
```

index.js:

```
const cwd = process.cwd();
const express = require(cwd + '/node_modules/express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;



app.use(express.static(cwd));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('chat message', msg => {
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
});

http.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Socket.IO server running at http://localhost:${port}/`);
});
```

ClientEncrypt.js (bundled with browserify):

```
window.encryptClient = () => {
    //document.getElementById("welcomeText").innerHTML = "poop";
    console.log("started");
    var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
    
    //var plainText = "Test";
    var plainText = document.getElementById("input").value;
    if(plainText == ''){
        console.log("Error, encrypt called while empty")
        return null;
    }
    var secretKey = "zdvB5oTxhVjxuFLBd8UJOOvNH3yton8POErBOza6n0z5OSKrNwniqA7mD5SNFTTZ";
    var cipherText = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plainText, secretKey);

    console.log("Encrypted Message: " + cipherText);
    //document.getElementById("welcomeText").innerHTML = cipherText;

    var decryptedPlainText = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherText, secretKey);
    console.log("Decrypted Message: " + decryptedPlainText.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));

    return cipherText;
}
```

Comment: You did not properly link to an image. Also, post all errors as text.

Comment: Could you try returning `cipherText.toString()`?

Comment: @PrerakSola That fixed the looping problem but nothing appears after the input box is cleared. Any clue why that's happening